# Importing a file, then turning it into a list of strings?

Tags: list, python-2.7, import

I'm trying to import a dictionary of words to use in a word game. The file I'm importing is a .rtf file with a single word on each line. I'd like to turn each line into an element of one large single list. The name of the file is "TextTwistDictionary.rtf". How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Is it in [rtf format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format) or in the plain text format? What do you see if you run `type TextTwistDictionary.rtf` or `cat TextTwistDictionary.rtf` in a console?

Answer (score 0):

```
list_words = []

with open('TextTwistDictionary.rtf') as f:
    for line in f: # read every line in the file
        list_words.append(line) # append each line to the list

print list_words
```

Comment: you could simplify it: `list_words = list(f)`

Comment: or you could use `readlines()`, but I wanted to show the OP what the general process is to read lines from a file and store them in a list.

Comment: Alright this code makes sense to me. Because the import file is extremely long, I can't print list_words without IDLE freezing on me, so I'll trust that it works.

Comment: @user2805672: you could call `with open('words.txt') as f: first_line = next(f)` or `first_line = f.readline()` to see whether you can read at least one word from the file. Note: don't mix calls that work with a file as an iterator and with calls to file methods such as `.read()`, `.readline()` - it might produce wrong result due to buffering.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open(fileName) as fileHandle:
    dictionary = fileHandle.readlines()
```